# How to write unwrapper for Church encoded free monad?(Haskell)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

How to write function like this? :

```
unWrap :: F f a -> Either a (f (F f a))
```

where F - Church encoded free monad.unWrap returns "a" if value is equals to "Pure a" or returns "f_" if value equals to "(Free f_)".

Comment: Can't you pattern-match against the constructors in the definition of `F f` ?

Comment: I see, it was not obvious to me that you were using `Control.Monad.Free.Church.F`, not a random type called `F` who happened to be a free monad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fromF`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Free-Church.html#v:fromF) to convert to another representation, in this case `Free f` so you can pattern-match, and `toF` to convert back from `Free f`.

```
unwrap :: Functor f => F f a -> Either a (f (F f a))
unwrap u = case fromF u of
  Pure x -> Left x
  Free v -> Right (fmap toF v)
```